# Akka .net inbox tutorial

Tags: akka.net

Hi there i have searched over the internet on how to configure and use **Inbox in Akka .net**,but I havent found any tutorials or examples regarding it.

If you have knowledge in **using Inbox in Akka.net** please share it.So that it will be helpful for others whom are also seeking for the same example.

Comment: The best place to look for is the Official website/documentation. Even though it is not fully complete it may help you. http://getakka.net/docs/Working%20with%20actors

Answer (score 2):

This link maybe help you: https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/ This web is a good source to search about akka.net